# Implement dependency in Codenvy Maven Project

Tags: eclipse, maven, codenvy

I wanted to test an existing Eclipse Maven Project in Codenvy Eclipse-Che.
The Project uses a LejosEV3 reposetory that is localy initiliazed in Maven.
directory: C:\Users\.m2\repository\lejos

In the Codenvy cloud service I couldn't find any option to implemet Lejos.

That's why I have uploadet the lejos directory to the /src of my Maven Project and implemented the following to the pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>lejos</id>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/src</url>
  </repository> 
</repositories>    
<dependencies>    
  <dependency>
    <groupId>lejos</groupId>
    <artifactId>ev3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
[..]
```

Now I get the following Error:
error: error reading /home/codenvy/.m2/repository/lejos/ev3/1.0/ev3-1.0.jar; error in opening zip file

[Help1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
(This page doesn't help at all)

But there is no .zip file, and there shouldn't be one. What .zip is he looking for? Any ideas?

EDIT:
[Link to my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvRjc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Were you following this guide? http://docs.codenvy.com/user/technology-specific-features/#upload-local-libs

[image]

Comment: Yes, only that my /repo folder is in my /src.

Comment: I just followed the guide and it works. Please, pay attention to details. Did you replicate maven repo structure? Or just uploaded the jar to src?

Take a look at the screenshot - I have updated my initial reply.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have uploadet a screenshot to and linket it in my initial Question (I'm not allowed to embedd images). I can't find any problems

Comment: It should work then. I have just tried it with another jar - it gets uploaded ok.

You may contact support@codenvy.com and share the jar - we'll take a look

Comment: Hmm, then I assume the .jar is corrupted or sth. I will contact the support. Thank you very much